# Few hourly events are missing in the splunk dashboard

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Need help on the below weird issue.

We have a Splunk query where it is built on the logs. Below is the query used.

```
index=aws_lle_airflow "INFO - Source count for aws-bda-lle.marketing.bq_mktg_campaign:"
| rex field=_raw "INFO - Source count for aws-bda-lle.marketing.bq_mktg_campaign: (?<bqTableRecordCount>[^\"]+)"
| table _time bqTableRecordCount
| sort _time
```

problem is ideally as per the table inserts 10 events should be displayed in the dashboard but only 8 events are shown.

Even though the logs are written not sure why the dashboard is not reflecting. Could someone help me what could be the issue and what needs to be done to resolve.

Comment: Have you verified all 10 events were successfully ingested into the same index, all have the expected text, and all have timestamps within the time frame being searched?

Comment: Nope those events didn't loaded into the index. May i know what could be the reason.and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: The reasons are as varied as the ways to get data loaded.  How are the events onboarded into Splunk?  It may help to share the relevant inputs.conf, props.conf, and transforms.conf settings.